# How to forward call to multiple numbers

Tags: phone-call, transfer, forwarding, vxml, vonage

How do I transfer the call to more then one number?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1">
 <form id="CallTransfer">
   <transfer name="MyCall" dest="tel:+15555555" bridge="true" >
  </transfer>

   </form>
 </vxml>
```

Answer (score 1):

The VoiceXML specification does not provide for the concept of a bridge/conference call to multiple parties.  If you have chosen a specific browser/vendor, they may provide extensions to the specification that do provide that functionality.